# How to "chroot/jail" execution of custom scripts in the R session?

Tags: r, encapsulation

I write a framework for testing for validity of R scripts and for analyzing their output. I don't want the script to be able to interact with each other in any way, but I do want to have a direct access to the R objects they left after execution.

The natural way to design this framework is to create a custom environment for each script and execute the script in it with something like `local(code, envir=custom_envir)`. Then I could inspect the environment for the leftover objects and efficiently work with them.

**Unfortunately, calls to `library` or `require` "leaks" outside the scripts' execution environment** - both functions insert package environment just after the `R_GlobalEnv`, which is eventually inherited by every script. So loading a library in one script changes the way the other script works - possibly breaking them (by changing the order of masked objects).

I don't want to run the scripts in separate R processes because the scripts produce heavy objects, and cross-process copying them may not fit in RAM. Serializing to disk is even worse.

How to "chroot jail" the execution of the script inside the existing R session, so that all memory effects of execution will be contained inside custom environment(s)?